# Checkmarx: How to avoid "Client_Hardcoded_URL" vulnerability from the comments.?

Tags: javascript, security, code-analysis, checkmarx

The checkmarx *"Client_Hardcoded_URL"* vulnerability defines the use of hardcoded URLs in Javascript code.

I have some comments written in the code as follows.

```
// from http://example.com
// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
// Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
```

When the checkmarx scan is executed the scan results are triggering the comments also. As a result the comments are also shown as potential cause for *"Client_Hardcoded_URL"* vulnerability.

How can i resolve this issue which is caused from maintaining hyperlinks in comments.?

Comment: Can you mark the result as "Not Exploitable"?

Comment: @ZviRosenfeld  How can we set the result to "Not Exploitable" in checkmarx?
I'm new to this tool.

Comment: @GeoJoseph I think you should ask your company's Checkmarx advisor.

Comment: @GeoJoseph, you can choose the "Not Exploitable" Option from the "Result State" combo box at the top right corner of the result grid. If you don't see the "Not Exploitable" option in the combo box it's because you don't have permission to set a result to "Not Exploitable". In that case, find out who in your company dose and contact them.